# ng-class does is not triggered on invalid form field

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am testing angular-fcsa-number directive, during the process the wrapper element of the input field is not assigned 'has-error' class even though the field is invalid. It seems to me that ng-class does not recognize that the field is invalid. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" name="form1">
    <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{ 'has-error': form1.fcsaPlugin.$invalid }">
        <label>FCSA Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="fcsaPlugin" class="form-control" data-ng-model="action.FV10036" fcsa-number />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you added the `fcsa-number` plugin as dependency to your application module? https://github.com/FCSAmericaDev/angular-fcsa-number#quick-start

Comment: Yes, I did. The functionality of the directive works fine (adding thousand separator, limit number of digit, etc.). It is just when it is invalid, it does not add the 'has-error' class to the wrapping element. I did see on Chrome Developer Tool that ng-invalid class is set up on the input and form element so I am not sure why the ng-class does not pick up on that.

Comment: this works well for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/gE1Y5NcVEi3K88h3gnQL?p=preview

Comment: I am combining ASP.NET WebForms and AngularJS. Apparently when I take out runat="server" attribute from the form tag, the ng-class works properly.

Comment: Try to add `data-ng-form="form1"` to form element

Comment: That actually throws an error 'Multiple directives [form, form] asking for 'form' controller on: <form id="form" name="form" data-ng-form="form1">'

Comment: Why would your input be invalid in the first place? There is no pattern, required, min, max, what should be invalidating it? The fcsa-number? what does that do? explain. Also, console.log form1 and look at $error object and see if there are any errors to make it invalid. I think you will find that your input is $valid, which is why has-error is not triggered. The ng-class code is good to go. Your probelem is somewhere else.

Comment: Could you please add the directive here?

Answer (score 0):

as you say it works when you remove the runat="server" attribute. Is by any chance you are using asp.net MasterPages. Had you tried to inspect the html, basically check the name of the form in the rendered html. if you are using MasterPage in asp.net the name of form will be aspnetForm, so your data-ng-class should be

```
data-ng-class="{ 'has-error': aspnetForm.fcsaPlugin.$invalid }"
```